# Developing Vert.x Modules with Maven in NetBeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, vert.x

I want to develop Vert.x applications using NetBeans IDE, How can i develop Vert.x Modules in NetBeans IDE? is it possible?

How can i create Vert.x Modules in NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

Developing Vert.x Modules in NetBeans IDE is very simple:

1. From `File` menu select `New Project`.
2. From Categories list select `Maven` and from Projects list select `Project from Archetype` and click Next.
3. In the Search textbox enter `io.vertx` and select `vertx-maven-archetype` from Archetype list and click nect.
4. Enter your Vert.x Modules name and properties and click finish.
5. For executing your mvn command you can right click on created project in `Projects` view and select `Customs -> Goals...` and enter your mvn command (e.g. vertx:runMod) in shown dialogue.